# 404 Page Not Found - CodeIgniter related

Tags: php, codeigniter, swiftmailer

I am using the Codeigniter framework in a project - I have a tool which reads an array and sends out over 10,000 emails using the SwiftMailer Email framework.

One form which I have once submitted is supposed to send out each individual email, however it doesnt sent out all of them as after a period of time I get the following error:

404 Page Not FoundThe page you requested was not found. - 500.shtml

The page itself doesnt actually redirect anywhere else so cannot understand why it would be saying this - anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're actually ending up with a 500 error, but when CI tries to display the custom error page for a 500 error (500.shtml), it can't find it, and so throws a 404 instead. Check your logs for the cause of the 500 error.

Comment: How do I remove this custom error page and just get it to load the default error page?

Answer (score 1):

It'll be a custom error page, probably set up on the web server itself. If it's an Apache server, check the httpd config and remove any [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) directives you don't want so you can see the actual error.

As Tom said, if this is happening after a significant delay, you're likely getting a timeout. The length of timeouts can be increased from the PHP end using [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) or the php.ini setting `max_execution_time`. However in general if you have a long-running task it is much better to run it in a background process than try to shoehorn it into an HTTP request.

Comment: hi guys - the max_execution_time is set to 360 so it is really weird.. i will keep investigating and come back shortly.

Comment: It is weird as this happens even though sometimes the actual entire duration can be as little as 30-40 seconds.. so I am little confused by it all.

Comment: Hmm. 30 seconds is the default PHP timeout, so I wonder if that's sticking? In any case, you should be able to get more information from the error message when you remove the 500 ErrorDocument that's obscuring it.

Comment: How would I check the ErrorDocument directives? (i ain't too great with Apache :)

Comment: Find the Apache config for your site. Where that is depends on how your instance is set up. It might be in the `conf/httpd.conf` file (relative to wherever Apache is installed) or it might be separated out into separate per-site files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enables`. It's also conceivable `ErrorDocument` might be hiding in an `.htaccess` file in your application itself.

Comment: Hi guys - am running the exact same script locally on our 'test' server and when submit the EXACT same script it returns the following:-

Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in D:\Web Sites\Sites\includes\swift-4.0.6\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php

Comment: Right, so you don't have an error redirect set up on your local test server. 120 seconds would seem to be the default timeout under WAMP. Again that should be changeable with `max_execution_time` in the `php.ini`. However I would suggest that 120 seconds is too slow for a web page to respond, so the mailing task should be done in a background process instead.